# function working in <script/> tag but not in external file

Tags: javascript, dom, vite, flowbite

I am on a Laravel project using Vite server for front rendering, also using flowbite and tailwind.
i'm trying to toggle a spinner by adding a specific function to buttons that i want. **i don't want to work with id.**

my function works perfectly in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pjq4byL1/25/).

but when I put it in an external file among my other files, it triggers :

> login:75 Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle_spinner is not defined
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

button.js:

```
function toggle_spinner(el) {
el.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

app.js

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
import 'flowbite';
import './sidebar';
import './charts';
import './buttons';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();
```

[image]

other exemple (sidebar.js)

```
    const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');

const toggleSidebarMobile = (sidebar, sidebarBackdrop, toggleSidebarMobileHamburger, toggleSidebarMobileClose) => {
    sidebar.classList.toggle('hidden');
    sidebarBackdrop.classList.toggle('hidden');
    toggleSidebarMobileHamburger.classList.toggle('hidden');
    toggleSidebarMobileClose.classList.toggle('hidden');
}

const toggleSidebarMobileEl = document.getElementById('toggleSidebarMobile');
const sidebarBackdrop = document.getElementById('sidebarBackdrop');
const toggleSidebarMobileHamburger = document.getElementById('toggleSidebarMobileHamburger');
const toggleSidebarMobileClose = document.getElementById('toggleSidebarMobileClose');
const toggleSidebarMobileSearch = document.getElementById('toggleSidebarMobileSearch');

toggleSidebarMobileSearch.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toggleSidebarMobile(sidebar, sidebarBackdrop, toggleSidebarMobileHamburger, toggleSidebarMobileClose);
});

toggleSidebarMobileEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toggleSidebarMobile(sidebar, sidebarBackdrop, toggleSidebarMobileHamburger, toggleSidebarMobileClose);
});

sidebarBackdrop.addEventListener('click', () => {
    toggleSidebarMobile(sidebar, sidebarBackdrop, toggleSidebarMobileHamburger, toggleSidebarMobileClose);
});
```

header :

```
<!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['resources/js/app.js'])
```

html :

```
<x-buttons.primary-button onClick="toggle_spinner(this.firstElementChild)" class="relative ml-3">
            <svg class="hidden mx-auto inline mr-3 w-4 h-4 text-white animate-spin" viewBox="0 0 100 101" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M100 50.5908C100 78.2051 77.6142 100.591 50 100.591C22.3858 100.591 0 78.2051 0 50.5908C0 22.9766 22.3858 0.59082 50 0.59082C77.6142 0.59082 100 22.9766 100 50.5908ZM9.08144 50.5908C9.08144 73.1895 27.4013 91.5094 50 91.5094C72.5987 91.5094 90.9186 73.1895 90.9186 50.5908C90.9186 27.9921 72.5987 9.67226 50 9.67226C27.4013 9.67226 9.08144 27.9921 9.08144 50.5908Z" fill="#E5E7EB"/>
                <path d="M93.9676 39.0409C96.393 38.4038 97.8624 35.9116 97.0079 33.5539C95.2932 28.8227 92.871 24.3692 89.8167 20.348C85.8452 15.1192 80.8826 10.7238 75.2124 7.41289C69.5422 4.10194 63.2754 1.94025 56.7698 1.05124C51.7666 0.367541 46.6976 0.446843 41.7345 1.27873C39.2613 1.69328 37.813 4.19778 38.4501 6.62326C39.0873 9.04874 41.5694 10.4717 44.0505 10.1071C47.8511 9.54855 51.7191 9.52689 55.5402 10.0491C60.8642 10.7766 65.9928 12.5457 70.6331 15.2552C75.2735 17.9648 79.3347 21.5619 82.5849 25.841C84.9175 28.9121 86.7997 32.2913 88.1811 35.8758C89.083 38.2158 91.5421 39.6781 93.9676 39.0409Z" fill="currentColor"/>
            </svg>
            <span id="connexion_button_content">{{ __('Log in') }}</span>
            <span class="sr-only"> {{ __('Log in') }}</span>
</x-buttons.primary-button>
```

my sidebar as my other elements at totaly working well so it can't be a file path or anything related to it...
Also, i have searched for hours and trying several option with "window.onload" etc etc .. i can't make this work.

again thank you, i know this question is often asked but i can't seem to see why it doesn't work.

Comment: `onclick` attributes require everything to be accessible in global scope. This is almost certainly not the case in your code. Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: @SebastianSimon then if i have let's say a bunch of buttons that have litteraly the same classes, but in some of those buttons, there are a bunch that i want to add this functionality and that, imagine, later, i want to add another button with the same functionality, i can't add the same id for all those button and i don't want one button to trigger that for all the buttons.